# SQL: Altered columns resulting in invisible columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have recently run into a problem with SQL tables where I had a mistake in my code that dropped a column in the table and after that recreated the column. This process was repeated many times until I discovered it.

But as a result it appears that the SQL table haven't properly deleted the columns. For instance I get this message when I want to add a new column:

"Warning: The table "Matches" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE to this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit."

And I also have trouble updating column values because they exceed the maximum limits.

And to be clear, the table does not have more than 30 (visible) rows and I only made each column a maximum of 40 varchars, so it appears that the dropped rows still exist somewhere. But how do I delete them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I associate that error with SQL Server, so I added the tag.

Comment: There are known issues with (some versions of) SQL Server incorrectly computing the row size after metadata changes. Try `DBCC CLEANTABLE` and/or `ALTER TABLE REBUILD`.